# NoSuchMethod exception while creating and formatting .doc file using Apache poi-3.8 beta hwpf

Tags: android, apache-poi

I am getting following Exception when trying to run this code.

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.POIDocument.< init >

Code Snippet:

```
try {

    File file = new File(externalPath + "/abc.doc");
    POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(new FileInputStream(file));
    HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);
    Range range = doc.getRange();
    CharacterRun run = range.insertAfter("Hello World!");
    run.setFontSize(2 * 18);
    run.setBold(true);
    run.setItalic(true);
    run.setCapitalized(true);
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(externalPath + "/agnew.doc"));
    doc.write(out);
    out.flush();
    out.close();

} catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e("Exception==","=="+ex.toString());
      ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Logcat:

```
Logcat : FATAL EXCEPTION: main : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.poi.POIDocument. : 
at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocumentCore.(HWPFDocumentCore.java:145) : 
at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument.(HWPFDocument.java:218) : 
at org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument.(HWPFDocument.java:186) : 
at com.vikas.prudent.CreateDocument.onCreate(CreateDocument.java:45) : 
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047) : 
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627) : 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679) : 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125) : 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033) : 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) : 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) : 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627) : 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) : 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) : 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868) : 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626) : 
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the exception, it appears to be lib version mis-match.  Looks like HWPFDocumentCore.java:145 is trying to construct a new POIDocument but cannot find the expected constructor to call.  I would take a look at line 145 of HWPFDocumentCore.java and see what constructor it is expecting.  Then look for a POI library which has such a constructor in the POIDocument.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have two copies of Apache POI on your classpath, and old one and a new one. My hunch is that your HWPF jar (Scratchpad) is new, but it's picking up an old core POI jar, which is why you're getting the exception.

What you need to do is review all the jars on your classpath, and identify the POI related jars, then ensure you have a consistent set of them.

The [POI FAQ](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) has [and entry on this very problem](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006), along with some Java code you can use to print out which jar the POI classes come from. If you can't spot the wrong jars directly, try porting something like the code shown there to your android code to help you find the older jar.